# How to read line by line using system call in C

Tags: c, linux, io, posix, system-calls

In my program, I can currently read char by char a file with given name "fichier1.txt", but what I'm looking for is to store a line(line char pointer here) and then display it that way :

-ligne 1 : content line 1

-line 2 : content line 2

-ect...

I've tried to store char by char but since it's a pointer and I'm yet that much familiar with pointers I'm not able to store a line and then reuse the pointer to store the char of the next line.

I have to say that it's part of a school projet and I have to use POSIX standard.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<errno.h>
#include<unistd.h>
#include<sys/types.h>
#include<sys/wait.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include<string.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

int main(){
    int read_fd, write_fd;
    off_t offset = 0;
    char lu;
    struct stat statFd;
    char *fichier = "fichier1.txt";


    read_fd = open(fichier,O_RDONLY);
    stat(fichier, &statFd);

    if(read_fd == -1){
        perror("open");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    int i = 0;
    char * line; // variable to store line

    while(lseek(read_fd,offset, SEEK_SET) < statFd.st_size)
    {
        if(read(read_fd, &lu, 1) != -1)
        {
            printf("%c",lu);
            offset++;

        } else {
            perror("READ\n");
            close(read_fd);
            close(write_fd);
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I'd like to use open() function and not fopen()

Comment: Don't include every header you can think of — include only those that you need.

Comment: Once you've opened the file you can get stat information with fstat, which avoids opening the file a second time and certain race conditions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you are able to read character after character from the file, the logic in `while` loop will be used to store an entire line (up to 199 characters, you can increase it though) at once in an array & then display it:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<stdlib.h>



int main(void)
{
    FILE *fptr=fopen( "fichier1.txt","r");
    int  i;
    char arr[200];     //THIS ARRAY WILL HOLD THE CONTENTS OF A LINE TEMPORARILY UNTIL IT IS PRINTED                       
    int temp_index=0,line_number=1;;
    memset(arr,'\0',sizeof(arr));

    while((i=getc(fptr))!=EOF)                         
    {
        if(i!='\n')                                
        {
            arr[temp_index++]=i; 
        }   
        if(i=='\n')
        {
            printf(line %d: %s\n",line_number++,arr);
            temp_index=0;
            memset(arr,'\0',sizeof(arr));
        } 
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Calling `lseek` at every iteration may be inefficient and may fail on devices which are incapable of seeking. I would write a program along these lines below if I don't need to store lines.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main (void)
{
    int lc = 0; /* line count */
    int c;      /* character read */

    FILE *fp = fopen("fichier1.txt", "r");
    if (fp == NULL) {
        perror("fopen");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    while ((c = fgetc(fp)) != EOF) {
        printf("line %d: ", ++lc);
        while (c != '\n' && c != EOF) {
            putchar(c);
            c = fgetc(fp);
        }
        putchar('\n');
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Or, a program using `fgets` to read a line at once:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

int main (void)
{
    int lc = 0; /* line count */
    char buf[4096]; /* buffer to store the line read */
    bool newline = true;

    FILE *fp = fopen("fichier1.txt", "r");
    if (fp == NULL) {
        perror("fopen");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    while (fgets(buf, sizeof buf, fp) != NULL) {
        if (newline)
                printf("line %d: ", ++lc);
        printf("%s", buf);
        newline = strchr(buf, '\n');
    }

    return 0;
}
```